# How do I remove functions from object output?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, ecmascript-5

I am learning about the *constructor pattern*.

To exercise what I am learning, I am building an in-memory model called `Book` inspired by the Mongoose API:

```
var assert = require("assert");

var Book = (function() {
    var books = [];
    var constructor = function(title, author, genre) {
        assert.ok(title, "title cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(author, "author cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(genre, "genre cannot be undefined");
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.save = function() {
            books.push(this);
        };
        this.description = this.title + "is a " + this.genre + " by " + this.author;
    };
    constructor.find = function() {
        return books;
    };
    return constructor;
}());
```

With this model, I can create `Book` instances and `save` them to an in-memory store:

```
var book = new Book("The Great Gatsby", "F. Scott Fitzgerald", "Novel");
book.save();
var books = Book.find();
console.log(books);

// [ { title: 'The Great Gatsby',
//    author: 'F. Scott Fitzgerald',
//    genre: 'Novel',
//    save: [Function],
//    description: 'The Great Gatsbyis a Novel by F. Scott Fitzgerald' } ]
```

**How do I remove the function property "save" from the output?** I only want to show the properties.

I need to know because, I want to send the `book` to the client using Express and I do not want to convolute the response with functions.

(I come from a C# background and in C#, I would override a function in the `System.Object` base class called `ToString` that functions *like* `console.log` use internally. I do not know of any equivalent in JavaScript.)

Comment: how would you be sending it from express to the client? JSON? if so, JSON removes the functions for you...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to override the default toString output:

```
var Book = (function() {
    var books = [];
    var constructor = function(title, author, genre) {
        assert.ok(title, "title cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(author, "author cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(genre, "genre cannot be undefined");
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.save = function() {
            books.push(this);
        };
        this.description = this.title + "is a " + this.genre + " by " + this.author;
    };
    constructor.find = function() {
        return books;
    };
    constructor.prototype.toString = function() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    };
    return constructor;
}());
```

Comment: This is a great answer because it does parallel what OP says he's familiar with from C#. Overrides `toString` with a call to `JSON.stringify` :)

Answer (score 0):

Short but hacky way:

```
books = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(books));
console.log(books);
```

> Note: `JSON.stringify` happens when you pass objects to the client via express using `res.json(book)`. If all you want is to send the object down to the client then you don't need to do anything but pass your object(s) to `res.json([obj|array])`.

Encapsulating the behavior on the object itself.

```
var Book = (function() {
    var books = [];
    var constructor = function(title, author, genre) {
        assert.ok(title, "title cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(author, "author cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(genre, "genre cannot be undefined");
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.save = function() {
            books.push(this);
        };
        this.description = this.title + "is a " + this.genre + " by " + this.author;
        this.stripFunctions = function () {
          var item = this;
          Object.keys(item).forEach(function (key) {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof item[key] === 'function') {
              delete item[key];
            }
          });
          return item;
        };
    };
    constructor.find = function() {
        return books;
    };
    return constructor;
}());

books = books.map(function (book) { return book.stripFunctions(); });
console.log(books);
```

Note that the above method will remove any functions from your object instance, meaning you won't be able to call them anymore after that.

PS - It's not part of your question, but you should consider adding methods to the prototype for your constructor so that you aren't creating new functions every time you create an instance of `Book`.

Also, I'll re-iterate that if you send objects down from express using `res.json` then it calls `JSON.stringify` for you, and when you stringify an object, functions get stripped off anyway.

Comment: If I can help it, I want to encapsulate that behaviour in the `Book` constructor.

Comment: I included a more general solution for you that will iterate over all the properties on the objects in the collection, check if the value is a function, and removes the property if it is. I'll add a constructor version. One sec.

Comment: Your `stripFunctions` method actually modifies the original object.

Comment: That was the intention; especially since he said he wanted on the object itself. All of my solutions modify the original object.

Comment: … meaning that as soon as you print it once, you cannot access its methods any more. So you completely break the object just for the simple purpose of logging it to the console…

Comment: Yeah I still don't see how that's a problem. His question was how to strip functions off the object, not how to copy an object and then strip them off.

Comment: I guess he does specify "output" a couple times which could be interpreted to mean he only wants this behavior on an outputted *copy*.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function on the prototype:

```
var Book = (function() {
    var books = [];
    function Book (title, author, genre) {
        assert.ok(title, "title cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(author, "author cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(genre, "genre cannot be undefined");
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.description = this.title + "is a " + this.genre + " by " + this.author;
    }
    Book.prototype.save = function () {
        books.push(this);
    };

    Book.find = function () {
        return books;
    };

    return Book;
}());
```

---

> If I can help it, I want to encapsulate that behaviour in the Book constructor.

That sounds like an odd requirement, but if you really need that (for whatever reason), you can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define the function without making it enumerable:

```
var Book = (function() {
    var books = [];
    function Book (title, author, genre) {
        assert.ok(title, "title cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(author, "author cannot be undefined");
        assert.ok(genre, "genre cannot be undefined");
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.description = this.title + "is a " + this.genre + " by " + this.author;

        Object.defineProperty(this, 'save', {
            value: function () {
                books.push(this);
            }
        });
    }

    Book.find = function () {
        return books;
    };

    return Book;
}());
```